# how do you shut down a silverlight out of browser app?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob

I'm running a Silverlight 4 app with elevated trust out of browser and cannot rely on the DOM or host web page to shut down Silverlight. There is no App.Current.Shutdown() method. How do I shut down a Silverlight app programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `App.Current.MainWindow.Close();`

Comment: Looks like this is only working with an out of browser application.

Comment: Since this question is only about OOB apps, this answer is entirely appropriate.